# Solution verification finding generating sets

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, solution-verification

$\bullet~$ Consider the vector space $K_{n}[x]$ over $K, n \geq 2$. Let $W_{1}$ and $W_{2}$ be subspaces of $K_{n}[x]$ defined by:

\begin{array}{l}
W_{1}=\left\{p(x) \in K_{n}[x] \mid p(0)=0\right\}\\ \quad  \quad \quad \quad \quad~\text{ and } \\
\left.W_{2}=\left\{p(x) \in K_{n} [ x\right] \mid p(1)=0\right\}
\end{array}

Find subsets $S_{1}$ and $S_{2}$ such that. $W_{1} \cap W_{2}=\left\langle S_{1}\right\rangle,$ and $W_{1}+W_{2}=\left\langle S_{2}\right\rangle .$ Verify that the set $W_{1} \cup W_{2}$ is not a subspace.

$\bullet~$**My attempt:**

$\circ~$For $\quad p(x) \in W_{1} \cap W_{2}$,

$p(x)$ Should satisfy $\quad p(x)=0, p(1)=0$

Let $~ p(x)=a_{n} x^{n}+a_{n-1} x^{n-1}+\cdots+a_{2} x^{2}+a_{1} x+a_{0}$

\begin{array}{l}
p(0)=0  \Rightarrow a_{0}=0 \\
p(1)=0 \Rightarrow a_{n}+a_{n-1}+\cdots+a_{2}+a_{1}=0
\end{array}

$\Rightarrow \quad p(x)=a_{n}\left(x^{n}-x\right)+a_{n-1}\left(x^{n-1}-x\right)......,+a_{2}\left(x^{2}-x\right)$
$\Rightarrow \quad W_{1} \cap W_{2}=\left\langle x^{n}-x_{1}, \ldots,  x^{2}-x\right\rangle$
$\Rightarrow S_{1}=\left\{x^{n}-x, x^{n-1}-x, \dots, x^{2}-x\right\}$

We know
**$ W_1\cup W_2 $ is subspace of $V$ iff
$W_1\subset W_2$ or $W_2\subset W_1$**

But neither $W_1\subset W_2$ nor $W_2\subset W_1$. Thus $W_1\cup W_2$ is not a subspace of $K_n[x]$

**For $S_2$:**

$W_1+W_2=\langle W_1\cap W_2 \rangle $

For this  first I find generating sets of $W_1$ and $W_2$
it comes out to be
$W_1=\langle x,x^2,....x^n \rangle$

$W_2=\langle x-1,x^2-1,x^3-1,.....x^n-1\rangle$

So , $W_1\cup W_2 = \langle x-1,x^2,x^3..... , x^n\rangle$

$\because$ every element of the generating set of  $W_2$ can be split  as

$x^k-1=(x-1)(x^{k-1}+x^{k-2}+\cdots+x+1)$

Except $(x-1)$  other terms are consumed by the generator of $W_{1}$

I want you to verify my solution if it has any error
Any other approach to  find $S_2$  will be appreciated, thankyou

Comment: Solution looks correct

Comment: Can you find dimension of each subspace?